# Physics for fun - not for books

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I have currently started and completed a lot of Ks3 physics papers. I have decided to go right back to basics so now I feel that I can start working at GCSE level but the only reference I can find to do this is BBC Bitesize. but I find that this only covers some parts and not others, I want something more in depth and can anyone point me in the right direction without me having to pay for an online course?

Comment: For Fun!!!...: )  seriously, do you know which area of physics you want to study. In general terms, http://www.physicsclassroom.com/  is a good general starting point, but it may feature  stuff you already know

Comment: I had a great time reading Feynmann lectures. It's college level but easily understandable. If you decide to study electrodynamics or quantum mechanics from the real basic then go for Griffiths.

Comment: Plenty of free resources online if you search for them.

Comment: Downvoting this seems a bit mean ...

Comment: Hi Kukki, have a look at our [book recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations).

Comment: Yes for fun :P I have plenty of time on my hands, like doing science stuff and I appreciate all the comments, I was looking at Quantum machanics and I would love to get to that but I am working my way there so I dont get lost.

Comment: I keep plugging this book so much,  people are going to think I have some stake in it, I don't.   **Quantum Mechanics by David McMahon** it's based around the author  doing lot (and lots) of worked exercises and imo, you will know after reading it if QM is for you. It's also got  typo's,  which keep you on your toes. Anybody with the math gained on leaving school,  say 16 year old upwards, can read it.

Comment: i have just googled it and my local libary has this available so i am going to be going to try and get this one day this week thank you

Comment: Things may have progressed since I was in school, but I don't think Quantum Mechanics is in the GCSE syllabus.

Comment: @JohnRennie : DV = "...does not show any research effort... is not useful."